# Symbols showing up in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sympy, symbols

I'm using sympy right now to code and graph something really quick, but I'm getting symbols in my arrays and I can't seem to get rid of them. Here is the code:

```
# Initial values
mass = [1, 20]
atomic_number = [1, 20]

# Symbols
Z1, Z2 = smp.symbols(r'Z_1 Z_2', integer = True)
alpha, c, E, mu, M1, M2 = smp.symbols(r'\alpha c E \mu M_1 M_2', real = True)

# Constants
h, k, c = 1, 1, 1
mu = M1*M2/(M1+M2)
E = h**2*k**2/(2*mu)
alpha = smp.Rational(1, 137)
M1, M2, Z1, Z2 = mass[0], mass[1], atomic_number[0], atomic_number[1]

form = q
rutherford = ((Z1*Z2*alpha*h*c)/(4*E*smp.sin(theta/2)**2))**2
eq = form**2*rutherford*smp.sin(theta)
form.subs(q, 2*smp.sin(theta/2))

eq_num = smp.lambdify(theta, eq_new)
theta_num= np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

print(eq_num(theta_num))
```

And what is printed is something that looks like

`6.66921657558027*M_1**2*M_2**2*Z_1**2*Z_2**2*q**2/(M_1 + M_2)**2`

But, I've already made M1, M2, Z1, and Z2 to be `mass[0]`, `mass[1]`, etc. I also can't just have `q = 2*smp.sin(theta/2)` because form is supposed to be a function of q. I've tried to use the `.subs()` command by replacing what comes after `eq` with this

```
eq_new = eq.subs([(M1, mass[0]), (M2, mass[1]), (Z1, atomic_number[0]), (Z2, atomic_number[1])], (q,1))

eq_num = smp.lambdify(theta, eq_new)
theta_num= np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)

print(eq_num(theta_num))
```

So, what do I do here?

Comment: `137)
M1, M2, Z1, Z2 = mass[0], mass[1], atomic_number[0], atomic_number[1]
` did not change `mu` or `E`.  Add more diagnostic prints.

Comment: When I put ```M1, M2, Z1, Z2 = mass[0], mass[1], atomic_number[0], atomic_number[1]``` before ```E``` or ```mu```, I printed ```E``` and it returned a number. However, when I printed ```eq_num(theta_num)```, it still returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have made several edits on the code. But, finally it works.

```
form = q
mass = [1, 20]
atomic_number = [1, 20]

Z1, Z2 = smp.symbols(r'Z_1 Z_2', integer = True)
alpha, c, E, mu, M1, M2 = smp.symbols(r'\alpha c E \mu M_1 M_2', real = True)

M1, M2, Z1, Z2 = mass[0], mass[1], atomic_number[0], atomic_number[1]
h, k, c = 1, 1, 1
mu = M1*M2/(M1+M2)
E = h**2*k**2/(2*mu)
alpha = smp.Rational(1, 137)

rutherford = ((Z1*Z2*alpha*h*c)/(4*E*smp.sin(theta/2)**2))**2
eq = form**2*rutherford*smp.sin(theta)
form.subs(q, 2*smp.sin(theta/2))

eq_num = smp.lambdify(theta, eq)
theta_num= np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
```

The main mistake that I was making earlier were

- Initializing the constants and equivalences after they're referenced
- Using `eq_new` on `eq_num` instead of just `eq`, as I've already used `eq_num` on another block.